# discord.errors.ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel

Tags: python, discord.py

So I made a piece of code with discord.py that plays an audio file when a user joins a voice channel. The problem is that I get the warning above. I think this is because when the bot joins it sees itself joining and can't join again. I have tried to solve this with the commented line of code, but that doesn't seem to work. The full error will be below the code. I'll only paste the code needed for this aspect of my bot, because the problem lies with this piece of code and not the rest. I also get this websocket closing warning, but do'nt know if it's important.

**Code:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member: discord.Member, before, after):
    vc_before = before.channel
    vc_after = after.channel
    path_mp3 = "Tutturuu.mp3"
    path_ffmpeg = r"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
    if vc_before == vc_after:
        return
    if vc_before is None:  # and member.display_name != discord.ClientUser.name:
        channel = member.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.connect()
        time.sleep(.5)
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=path_ffmpeg, source=path_mp3))
        with audioread.audio_open(path_mp3) as f:
            time.sleep(f.duration)
        await vc.disconnect()
    elif vc_after is None:
        return
    else:
        channel = member.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.connect()
        time.sleep(.5)
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=path_ffmpeg, source=path_mp3))
        with audioread.audio_open(path_mp3) as f:
            time.sleep(f.duration)
        await vc.disconnect()
```

**Full error:**
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\yorbe\OneDrive\Documenten\Folders\Gerbinbot_3000\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:/Users/yorbe/OneDrive/Documenten/Folders/Gerbinbot_3000/main.py", line 109, in on_voice_state_update
vc = await channel.connect()
File "C:\Users\yorbe\OneDrive\Documenten\Folders\Gerbinbot_3000\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1115, in connect
raise ClientException('Already connected to a voice channel.')
discord.errors.ClientException: Already connected to a voice channel.
websocket connection is closing.
websocket connection is closing.
websocket connection is closing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out how to fix this myself. just add this code(see between the header) in front if vc_before == vc_after

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member: discord.Member, before, after):
     vc_before = before.channel
    vc_after = after.channel
    path_mp3 = "Tutturuu.mp3"
    path_ffmpeg = r"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
    -----------------
    for role in member.roles:
        if role.name == "Name of the role that your bot made when it joined the server, 
usually its own name":
            return
    -----------------
    if vc_before == vc_after:
        return
    if vc_before is None:
        channel = member.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.connect()
        time.sleep(.5)
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=path_ffmpeg, source=path_mp3))
        with audioread.audio_open(path_mp3) as f:
            time.sleep(f.duration)
        await vc.disconnect()
    elif vc_after is None:
        return
    else:
        channel = member.voice.channel
        vc = await channel.connect()
        time.sleep(.5)
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=path_ffmpeg, source=path_mp3))
        with audioread.audio_open(path_mp3) as f:
            time.sleep(f.duration)
        await vc.disconnect()
```